# python find similarity in list

Tags: python, list

I want to have function that take a list and based on sensitivity give me that numbers that are similar like `[4,4.01,3.9]` or `[71,69,72]`

I tried subtracting each value and if it`s less than sensitivity add those numbers to a tuple for example:

```
abs(4 - 4.01)= 0.01 => 0.01 < 0.5 => result += [(4,4.01)]
```

or

```
abs(4.01 - 3.9)= 0.11 => 0.11 < 0.5 => result += [(4.01,3.9)]
```

but it`s output is

```
[(4, 4.1), (4, 3.9), (4.1, 4), (4.1, 3.9), (3.9, 4), (3.9, 4.1)]
```

i don't want this i want `[4.01,4,3.9]` from `[4,4.01,3.9,5,10,45]`

python

```
def collation(arr):
    ret = []
    xi = 0
    while xi < len(arr):
        yi = 0
        while yi < len(arr):
            if (xi == yi):
                yi += 1
                continue
            if (abs(arr[xi] - arr[yi]) <= Sens):
                ret += [(arr[xi], arr[yi])]
            yi += 1
        xi += 1
    return ret
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. the question title does not align with the explanation. and the explanation could be made cleaner. Could you see if you could tweak the explanation and question further to improve it? Also, some more concrete examples might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`filter`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) function in order to get all these values that satisfy your condition:

```
inlist = [4,4.01,3.9,5,10,45]
point_value = 4
threshold = 0.5
outlist = list(filter(lambda elem: round(abs(elem-point_value),2) <= threshold, inlist))
print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[4, 4.01, 3.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

similarities = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))

print("Similarities between list1 and list2 are:", similarities)
```